# Make a UNION return a single result in SPARQL

Tags: sparql, graphdb, shacl

I am trying to query for the `sh:description` of a property shape, and if there is none, I want to follow the path to a property and get the `rdfs:comment` (Also for `sh:name` and `rdfs:label`). My data looks like the following:

```
ex:File
  a owl:Class ;
  a sh:NodeShape ;
  sh:property ex:File-name ;

ex:File-name
  a sh:PropertyShape ;
  sh:path ex:filename ;
  sh:datatype xsd:string ;
  sh:description "The name of the file" ;
  sh:maxCount 1 ;

ex:filename
  a rdf:Property ;
  rdfs:label "Filename" ;
  rdfs:comment "The file name" ;
.
```

I have the query below, but it returns two results. How can I modify it to only return a single result (preferring `sh:description` over `rdfs:comment`)?

```
PREFIX : <http://www.example.org/#>
PREFIX sh: <http://www.w3.org/ns/shacl#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
select ?propertyShape ?property ?name ?description where {
    :File sh:property ?propertyShape .
    ?propertyShape sh:path ?property .
    { ?propertyShape sh:name ?name } UNION { ?property rdfs:label ?name } .
    { ?propertyShape sh:description ?description } UNION { ?property rdfs:comment ?description } .
```

The above returns something like this:

| propertyShape | property | name | description |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| :File-name | ex:filename | "Filename" | "The name of the file" |
| :File-name | ex:filename | "Filename" | "The file name" |

I would like for it to return something like:

| propertyShape | property | name | description |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| :File-name | ex:filename | "Filename" | "The name of the file" |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use a sequence of `OPTIONAL` blocks to do this:

```
SELECT ?propertyShape ?property ?name ?description WHERE {
    :File sh:property ?propertyShape .
    ?propertyShape sh:path ?property .

    OPTIONAL { ?propertyShape sh:name ?name }
    OPTIONAL { ?property rdfs:label ?name }

    OPTIONAL { ?propertyShape sh:description ?description }
    OPTIONAL { ?property rdfs:comment ?description }
}
```

You'll still have to think about cases where there are multiple names/descriptions per property (this isn't guaranteed to return just a single result), but it should give you the "preferring sh:description over rdfs:comment" behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just use path expressions such as

```
...
?propertyShape sh:name|(sh:path/rdfs:label) ?name .
?propertyShape sh:description|(sh:path/rdfs:comment) ?description .
```

Comment: This seem to give me every combination of `sh:name`, `sh:description`, `rdfs:label`, and `rdfs:comment`. Returning up to four results per propertyShape